# implode() an array except on last entry

Tags: php, arrays, xml, implode

I am using PHP to create an XML document from a database to import into Adobe InDesign. I want to be able to add a comma after each  entry but not on the last one. I have tried using `implode()` but I have had no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code with out any attempt at adding the comma. I can just add a comma after the closing  but that will still give me one on the last entry.

```
function getAssocXML ($company) {
    $retVal = "";

    // Connect to the database by creating a new mysqli object
    require_once "DBconnect.php";

    $staffResult = $mysql->query("
        SELECT company,
               fName,
               lName,
               title,
               contact1,
               contact2
          FROM staff
         WHERE company = '$company'
           AND title
          LIKE '%Associate%'
           AND archive = 0
    ");

    if ($staffResult->num_rows >= 1 && $staffResult->num_rows < 4) {
        $retVal = $retVal;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $staffResult->num_rows; $i++) {
            // Move to row number $i in the result set.
            $staffResult->data_seek($i);
            // Get all the columns for the current row as an associative array -- we named it $aRow
            $staffRow = $staffResult->fetch_assoc();
            // Write a table row to the output containing information from the current database row.
            $retVal = $retVal . "<staff>";
            $retVal = $retVal . "<name>" . $staffRow['fName'] . " " . $staffRow['lName'] . "</name>";
            $retVal = $retVal . "<contact>" . staffContact($staffRow['contact1'], $staffRow['contact2']) . "</contact>";
            $retVal = $retVal . "</staff>";
        }

        $retVal = $retVal . " &#x2014; Associate&#xD;";
        $staffResult->free();
    }

    if ($staffResult->num_rows > 4) {
        $retVal = $retVal;
        $retVal = $retVal . "<staffHeader>Associates: </staffHeader>";

        for ($i = 0; $i < $staffResult->num_rows; $i++) {
            // Move to row number $i in the result set.
            $staffResult->data_seek($i);
            // Get all the columns for the current row as an associative array -- we named it $aRow
            $staffRow = $staffResult->fetch_assoc();
            // Write a table row to the output containing information from the current database row.
            $retVal = $retVal . "<staff>";
            $retVal = $retVal . "<name>" . $staffRow['fName'] . " " . $staffRow['lName'] . "</name>";
            $retVal = $retVal . "<contact>" . staffContact($staffRow['contact1'], $staffRow['contact2']) . "</contact>";
            $retVal = $retVal . "</staff>";
        }

        $retVal = $retVal . "&#xD;";
        $staffResult->free();
    }

    return $retVal;
}

print getAssocXML(addslashes($aRow['company']));
```

Comment: Can this [mcve] be made more minimal and more clear?  Can we have simple static input data and an exact desired output from that sample data?  Please remove all irrelevant code and simplify the problem.  Improving this question may make this page a better candidate to help future readers and potentially make a good dupe target when closing newly asked questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the help of this query

```
echo join(' and ', array_filter(array_merge(array(join(', ', array_slice($array, 0, -1))), array_slice($array, -1)), 'strlen'));
```

> OR

```
$last  = array_slice($array, -1);
$first = implode(', ', array_slice($array, 0, -1));
$both  = array_filter(array_merge(array($first), $last), 'strlen');
echo implode(' and ', $both);
```

Comment: Note that `join` is an alias of the PHP function, `implode`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that I don't readily grasp your intent here. I don't see anything in your code that is using any sort of array, which is a pre-requisite for `implode()` *(a.k.a. `join()`)*

However, here's a little trick that I've used numerous times when I am building something *in a loop*:

```
 $result = "";
 $comma  = "";
 foreach (...) {
   .. calculate some $value ..
   $result = $result . $comma . $value;
   $comma = ",";
 }
```

The *first* time through the loop, `$comma` *isn't* a comma!   It's an empty string.   At the end of the first iteration through the loop, it becomes a comma, for use *next* time. It's a simple but effective way to build an arbitrarily-long "comma-separated string" in-place.

*HTH!*