# Change the color of commas in php

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
   $tagstrings = array();
   foreach($posttags as $tag) {
      $tagstrings[] = '<a href="' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '" class="tag-link-' . $tag->term_id . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
   }
   echo implode(', ', $tagstrings);
}

// For an extra touch, use this function instead of `implode` to a better formatted string
// It will return "A, B and C" instead of "A, B, C"
function array_to_string($array, $glue = ', ', $final_glue = ' and ') {
    if (1 == count($array)) {
        return $array[0];
    }
    $last_item = array_pop($array);
    return implode($glue, $array) . $final_glue . $last_item;
}
?>
```

The code puts a comma after tags in WP (except the last tag). I would like to change the color of commas.  How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$glue = '<span class="tagglue">,</span> ';
```

and use that in your `implode()` calls (either place in your snippet).

Then create a css declaration like:

```
.tagglue {color: blue;}
```

Implementation:

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
   $tagstrings = array();
   foreach($posttags as $tag) {
      $tagstrings[] = '<a href="' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '" class="tag-link-' . $tag->term_id . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
   }
   echo array_to_string($tagstrings);
}

// For an extra touch, use this function instead of `implode` to a better formatted string
// It will return "A, B and C" instead of "A, B, C"
function array_to_string($array, $glue = '<span class="tagglue">, </span>', $final_glue = ' and ') {
    if (1 == count($array)) {
        return $array[0];
    }
    $last_item = array_pop($array);
    return implode($glue, $array) . $final_glue . $last_item;
}
?>
```

---

I'll take this change to link several related pages on StackOverflow (that don't offer coloration):

- [Implode array with ", " and add "and " before last item](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8586141/2943403)
- [Imploding with "and" in the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22831997/2943403)
- [Separate an array with comma and string PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52193927/2943403)
- [implode() an array with multiple database columns, except on last entry PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38878016/2943403)
- [Comma separated list from array with "and" before last element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18476587/2943403)
- [PHP Add commas to items with AND](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9065929/2943403)
- [Replace the last comma with an & sign](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7687665/2943403)
- [How to replace last comma in string with "and" using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41762925/2943403)

Comment: I changed my code, as you wrote, but nothing happened
   
`function array_to_string($array, $glue = '<span class="tagglue">, </span>', $final_glue = ' and ')`

Comment: Please check the source code to see if the `<span>` tags were generated as intended.  Did you add the `.tagglue {color: blue;}` declaration to the stylesheet?  Is the style declaration in the source code?

Comment: It strange. I changed my code, but I can't see the alteration in source. The span class="tagglue" absolutely miss.

Comment: How about clearing the cache?  Hard refresh the page reload?  Can you check the last_modified datetime on the file that you are editing?  These little hiccups happen, continue to investigate and let me know if you get any clues.  Is the function actually getting called? or is your file merely echoing the first portion of your posted snippet?  Do you need: `echo array_to_string($tagstrings);` after your foreach() loop?

Comment: I deleted the cache (ctrl+shift+r). My code is just such as above.